# How to load custom tensorflowJS model in react-native?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I've converted my Keras model into TensorflowJS using tensorflowjs_converter. It generated a single 'model.json' file and 9 '*.bin' file. I'm trying to load this model using following function.

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
```

modelWeights is only selecting a single weight. But I have 9 of them. How can I load this model correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I just found a solution. Basically tensorflow_converter breaks the weights into some smaller sizes. But if you increase the size limit of weight files, the number of files generated will be decreased. Let's say your model weights file takes 30MB. So, increaes the limit to >=30MB, it will generate only a single weight file. You can do this by following the command below:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras --weight_shard_size_bytes 60000000 'your_model.h5' 'output_dir'
```